# Can this algorithm be improved to linear time?

Tags: python

I have a counter like below:

```py
counter = Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd':1, 'e':1})
```

I want to update its count based on lookup from another dictionary, `dict1`, which stores compatibility information of keys in the counter. For example, in `dict1`,

```
'a': ['b','d']
```

`'a'` is compatible with `'b'` and `'d'`, so I want to update `a`'s count from 2 to 4, because it is both compatible with `b` and `d`.

I wrote this piece of code, but it uses two loops. Is it possible to use one loop to achieve the same effect?

```py
counter = Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd':1, 'e':1})
dict1 = {'a': ['b','d'], 'b':['a','d'], 'd':['a','b'], 'c':['e'], 'e':['c']}

keys = list(counter.keys())
count = len(keys)
for i in range(count):
    current = keys[i]
    for j in range(i+1, count):
        next = keys[j]
        comps = dict1.get(current, None)
        if comps and next in comps:
            counter[current] += 1
```

Comment: It's not clear (to me) why `a` moves to `4`. Is it because `b=1` and `d=1` therefor `2+1+1 = 4`? If so, your code doesn't produce the correct result for `b` it produces `2` for the new value of `b` not `4`. Or does order matter here?

Comment: I don't understand why you limit the range of the second loop.  Don't you have to compare all the keys against all of the lists in `dict1`?  That is, I think you'd want `for j in range(count):` and then just to exclude the case of `i == j`.  If that's right, I might see an optimization.

Comment: With the example you give, it seems that  for `k = 'a', v = ['b','d']`, you just want `counter[k] += len(v)`.  Given your description, it doesn't seem to even matter what the terms in the inner lists are.  If that's true, then you could walk across `dict1`, applying this simple operation just once on each k/v pair.  However, this is not what your code is doing.  Your code clearly is influenced by the actual values in the inner lists.  So it seems to me that your code doesn't match your description

Answer (score 1):

### **No, you can't do better than quadratic.**

Let `n` be the number of keys in the counter. Then, each key can be compatible with `O(n)` other keys, for which we must do linear work in order to enumerate. There are `n` keys, so we have an operation that must take at least `O(n)` time, repeated across `n` keys, meaning that the best we can do is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done in linear time since you need to sum over all compatible values for all keys in `counter`. You *can* do this much more cleanly though:

```py
In [3]: {k: sum(map(counter.get, dict1[k]), v) for k, v in counter.items()}
Out[3]: {'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 4, 'e': 2}
```

BTW I don't think your result is correct, unless I'm misunderstanding your logic.